# Reading contact phone numbers works for some and not others?

Tags: android, android-contacts, phone-number

I am reading contact names and phone numbers from the contacts list in Android. I am reading the names successfully. However, when I go to look up a contact phone number by name (which are all unique in this case, it's just a test), it works perfectly for only one contact, gets no phone number for others, and gets the wrong phone number for one.

Here is the code in my getNumbers method:

```
private String getNumber(String name){
    String returnMe="";
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
            "DISPLAY_NAME = '" + getIntent().getStringExtra("name") + "'", null, null);

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        String identifier = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        Cursor phones = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID + " = " + identifier, null, null);
        while(phones.moveToNext()){
            returnMe = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            int type = phones.getInt(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
            switch(type){
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
                    System.out.println("mobile number found"); break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("nothing found."); break;
            }
        }
    }
    return returnMe;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing a few things wrong:

1) The second query must target the [Data](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html) table, not the Phone table:

```
Cursor phones = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, ...
```

and specify that you want the Phone number in the DATA1 column in the where clause:

```
Data.MIMETYPE = Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
```

2) You need to filter the results by the RawContact's _ID

This compares the _ID of the Contact row with the _ID of the Phone row, which have very little chance to be the same:

```
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID + " = " + identifier
```

This compares the Data.CONTACT_ID with the cursor's Contact._ID property

```
Data.CONTACT_ID + " = " + identifier
```

The example on the [Data](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html) javadoc page gives a more complete example:

*Finding all Data of a given type for a given contact*

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI,
      new String[] {Data._ID, Phone.NUMBER, Phone.TYPE, Phone.LABEL},
      Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND "
              + Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'",
      new String[] {String.valueOf(contactId)}, null);
```

Comment: Glad I could help. As a matter of fact, I think the other answer works too and uses only the Contacts table, so it's simpler. The contacts are organized in 3 tables: Contacts, RawContacts and Data. Each table has a corresponding class, e.g. ContactsContract.Contacts. Then you need to join the results using the proper keys, as you would do in a SQL query. Make sure you read the doc about all that https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer:

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
    String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
    if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
        //Query phone here
      if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
        Cursor pCur = cr.query(
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
        null, 
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", 
        new String[]{id}, null);
        while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
        // Get phone numbers here
        } 
        pCur.close();
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the sample, but I'm really interested in learning rather than deciphering. Can you give me an explanation as to what you're doing and why you're doing it that way versus another?

Comment: Its giving me same contacts multiple times.